# Why does the page reload after running this script

Tags: javascript, button

I'm exploring javascript now.
     The following code runs correctly, but after I click the  button, the page is refreshing. This is not desired.
     Any help would be appriciated. 
     Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body >  
<form>
<input onchange="chk_change();" type="checkbox" id="chk_city" checked="checked"><label     for="chk_city">All cities</label></input><br>
<select id="sel1" style="display:none;margin:20 0 0 0;padding:3; width:100">
<option id="opt1">London
<option id="opt2">Moscow
<option id="opt3">Tokyo</option>
</select>
<br>
<button id="btn1" onclick="aa();">Go</button><br>
<p id="p1" style="border:1px solid black;width:200;height:50"></p>
</form>
</body>



<script type="text/javascript" >
function chk_change(){

var ch=document.getElementById('chk_city').checked;
    if (ch ==true){
     ch=document.getElementById('sel1').style.display='none';
    }
    else {
    ch=document.getElementById('sel1').style.display='block';
    }

}



function aa(){

sel = document.getElementById('sel1');

var text=(sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text);
var ch=document.getElementById('chk_city').checked;
    if (ch ==true){
    document.getElementById('p1').innerText="All cities";
    }
    else{
    document.getElementById('p1').innerText=text;
    }
}

</script>


</html>
```

Comment: A `<button>` in a form is a submit button, which posts the form, which likely (re)loads a page. Make it a `type="button"` or handle the event with JS if you don't want to post the form on click.

Comment: I see no reason that wouldn't work, but try removing the `<form>`, it could possibly be connected.

Comment: @Chris there is no jquery involved and it is not tagged with it

Comment: @Huangism It doesn't matter, the default action of a button is the same whether jQuery is involved or not. The accepted answer is not related to jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default behavior of any button in a form is to be a submit button, which means that it will cause the page to reload. Set the property `type='button'` on the button and it will act just as a plain button, without submitting anything.

Comment: You can `<button type="button">` ?? That seems redundant.

Comment: It does, but I promise, it'll work.

Comment: I was literally yelling about it when I found this out at work. Don't know why I got a downvote -- it's 100% real.

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/button.button.html

Comment: `document.createElement('button').type` is apparently "submit". Kewl. Downvote not mine.

Comment: Return false from the handler, prevent default, or button-button... all valid approaches.

Comment: button-button =) HTML is so sensible and logical!

Comment: You should see the button-button-button! When you click it, Xzibit pops out and hands you a button.

Comment: @Rudie Better would be to set an `<input type="button">`

Comment: @jmpp "better" in what regard?

Comment: @jmpp Maybe better, but not the same. You can add markup inside a `<button>`, very useful, even an `<img>` etc.

Comment: @Chris For not being "redundant" :) It's about preferences.

Comment: @Rudie Yes. It depends of your purposes

Comment: @jmpp I disagree. The redundancy is only a perception of the developer looking at the code, whereas the `button` tag with a type of "button" is the semantic choice for a button without any other semantics. An input that is a button is semantically a mess.

Comment: Thanks to all. The Problem is solved due to <input type="button" ...